# I reached mouseEntered limit

Tags: java, limit, mousemotionlistener

I think I reached `mouseEntered` limit, so... can I somehow add two `mouseEntered` in one class ? Or is there other way ? I'am not going to post code, it's longer than 65535 bytes limit

Comment: This isn't clear - what "limit" are you talking about?

Comment: If I hover my mouse on `mouseEntered` it will show: "The code of method mouseEntered(MouseEvent) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit"

Comment: That sounds like a limitation of your IDE.

Comment: And can I do something with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java class file format has a limit for the size of a single method. Split your `mouseEntered` method into smaller methods.

Comment: With cut and paste? How do you end up with 64kB of code in a single method in the first place?

Comment: Ummmm.... beacuse I have 400 `JLabels` and 3 events for every one + something else. And how can I split methods ???

Comment: create a new method, maybe call it `mouseEnteredPart2`. Move some code from `mouseEntered` to `mouseEnteredPart2`. Call `mouseEnteredPart2` from `mouseEntered`.

Comment: And how can I call `mouseEnteredPart2` from `mouseEntered` ? I hope that is last question.